# IBM AIX cannot view history in bash shell

Tags: bash, aix, command-history

The AIX user I su to daily has no history from SSH session to SSH session. I'm using the bash shell because the Korn shell alternative does not autocomplete which is an even bigger nuisance.

I already put the lines in the .profile file in the home folder:

```
export HISTSIZE=10000
export EXTENDED_HISTORY=ON
```

I don't have the root password to modify /etc/profile.

When I do

```
ls $HISTFILE
```

I get */users/me/.bash_history* instead of */users/user_I_su_to/.bash_history*

I also tried adding to file */users/user_I_su_to/.bash_history* the line:
     export HISTFILE=/usagers/user_I_su_to/.bash_history

Naturally I logged out of my SSH sessions and back in to apply.

Comment: Is $HISTFILE set to something valid?

Comment: ls $HISTFILE gives me /users/wronguser/.bash_history  I am "wronguser", the history I want is for the user I su'ed to. I tried adding in .profile export HISTFILE=/users/suedto/.bash_history  but that doesn't seem to work (?)

Comment: Burying surprises in question comments does not make for good questions or answers.  _Your question should mention_ these facts straight off the bat.

Comment: You can enable ksh autocompletion. `set -o vi-tabcomplete` and If you're using stock ksh, you can use "Esc-\" for completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this. The history is correctly displayed if I su using the syntax:

```
su - user_I_su_to
```

instead of:

```
su user_I_su_to
```